# Postgresq: Subquery and math

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm working on a dataset with information on recorded arrests and need to find the answer to this question:

How many arrests occurred between 12 am and 4 am in 2018? What percentage of arrests occurred during these hours compared to the whole 24 hr period?

I was able to find how many arrests were made during that time frame with:

```
select count(reportid)
from arrests 
where adate::varchar like ‘%2018%’
and tim between ‘0000’ and ‘0400’;
```

But I don't know how to go about creating a subquery to find out what percentage that would be compared to the whole 24 hour period.

I'm new to sql and appreciate any help. Also, please let me know if more information is needed to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery:

```
select
    sum(case when tim between '0000' and '0400' then 1 else 0 end) as early_hours_count,
    sum(case when tim between '0000' and '0400' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) as ealry_hours_percentage
from arrests 
where extract(year from adate) = '2018'
```

Rather than *counting* rows after applying a filter, this *calculates* how many by summing `1` if the arrest happened between 0:00 and 4:00 or `0` otherwise.

Note also the more straightforward approach to the `where` clause filtering for year.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you mind explaining to me why a subquery isn't needed here? Is it impossible to use in this case or is it just that your way is more sensible?

Comment: @user13451867 you can use a subquery, and it’s possibly more readable as a subquery, but this does one pass over the data, instead of 2 passes required by the use of a subquery, and so it’s more efficient. Also, subqueries are harder to use as the query complexity grows, but approaches like this usually stay tidy.